# JQuery UI Autocomplete, change event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've some problems with JQuery Autocomplete, my code it's like:

```js
var mySource = [{"label":"Value one","id":"1"},{"label":"Value two","id":"2"},{"label":"Value three","id":"3"}];

$("#txtAutocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: mySource,
  select: function(event, ui){
    if(ui.item){
      //console.log('select', ui.item.label);
      $("#hiddenField").val(ui.item.id);
      return ui.item.label;
    }
    else{
      //console.log('select with null value');
      $("#hiddenField").val('');
    }
  },
  change: function(event, ui){
    if(ui.item){
      //console.log('change', ui.item.id);
      $("#hiddenField").val(ui.item.id);
    }
    else{
      //console.log('change with null value');
      $("#hiddenField").val('');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>
  <ol>
    <li>Type 'Value' in the text box</li>
    <li>Press 'arrow down' to select the first element</li>
    <li>Press enter</li>
    <li>Keep pressed backspace to delete completely the selected item</li>
    <li>Press TAB</li>
    <li>Value in 'readonly' field is still there</li>
  </ol>
</p>

<input type="text" id="txtAutocomplete">
<input type="text" id="hiddenField" disabled="disabled">

<button>Button added just to have an element to focus on</button>
```

When I put the string 'value' in the editable field, autocomplete appears correctly, so I can select one value and put it in the textbox with id `hiddenField`.
Then, if I clear the value in the textbox, I can't update the related `hiddenField` with a blank value, because `change` event doesn't fire. Why?

Steps to test snippet:

- Write 'value' in the editable field
- Select one value
- Clear the selected value

`hiddenField` will still contain old value.

Thanks

**Note:** It doesn't work when I clear the field after selection but still keeping the focus on it.

**Updated:** I reported the bug [here](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15154) on bugs.jqueryui.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to keep the inputs in sync inside the autocomplete options. Attach a separate event handler to your text input like so:

```js
$("#txtAutocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'],
  select: function(event, ui){
      console.log('select', ui.item.value);
      $("#hiddenField").val(ui.item.value);
  }
});
$("#txtAutocomplete").on("input propertychange", function () {
    console.log("change", this.value);
    $("#hiddenField").val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtAutocomplete">
<input type="text" id="hiddenField" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to put the id of the selected item only if it's in the list. I updated my snippet so you could see how it works with the pair key/value.

Comment: Well, on `confirm` button of my dialog I added a check like: `$("#txtAutocomplete").val()==""`, if it's `true` then I clear the value of `hiddenField`. So I used a solution, more or less, similar to yours.that's to attach a separate event handler. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have run to this problem and there is a hack to avoid the problem. You have to force a blur but with a setTimeout

```
   if(ui.item){
     //console.log('select', ui.item.label);
     $("#hiddenField").val(ui.item.id);
      setTimeout(function () {
                    $(event.target).blur();                       
                });
     return ui.item.label;
   }
```

Comment: I love you; I've been stuck with this for way too long

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code snippet, the change event does get fired each time I select an item, or when I clear the value, and the log gets printed. But the event gets fired only after I tab out after a selection, or after I click outside the auto-complete input element.

This is because, as per the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change), the change event gets fired only when the element loses focus.

Steps that make it work:

- Write 'test' in the editable field, and select an option
- Tab out - this fires the change event
- Delete the value
- Tab out - this fires the change event

Comment: Yes, it fires only when I leave the field by pressing TAB, it's a little strange, anyway users most probably will click directly on the button to send the form.