# jQuery autocomplete accept initial value

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete in many of my forms.  I have overridden the change function so that if the user types an entry that does not exist in the database, it clears the field and adds a small error message (see code below).  I have run across a problem where if I provide an initial value at page load (I am using Django to control my forms), once the page loads, the field seems fine, but if the user just touches that field without making any changes (tabbing through the form, for example, or clicking on the field but not making any changes, then leaving), it registers an error.  The initial value inserted by Django is valid and in the database, but autocomplete thinks it does not exist.

```
$("#field-id").autocomplete({
            source: "/lookup",
            autoFocus: true,   //Just press enter to select top item
            minLength: 0,
            delay:50,
            change: function (event, ui) {  //if detects a string that was not suggested (meaning does not exist in DB), clear value and show not valid
                if (!(ui.item)) {
                    $(this).val("");
                    errorShow(this, "invalid selection") //Display error message under input
                }
            }
        });
```

This works fine if the field is initially blank, but if the field contains an initial value, autocomplete doesn't check if it's valid.

When the page loads, I have tried to check if the field has a value or not, and then various combinations of triggering the change in the field and triggering "select", all with no luck.  For example:

```
if ($("#field-id").val() !=""){
    $("#field-id").autocomplete("search").data("ui-autocomplete")._trigger("change");
    $("#field-id").trigger("select");
}
```

or

```
if ($("#field-id").val() !=""){
        $("#field-id").trigger("input").trigger("select");
    }
```

It seems to show the dropdown briefly, but then just clears the field and displays the error as if it does not exist.

How does one get autocomplete to correctly recognize a valid initial value in an autocomplete-enabled field?  Ideally, if there is a default value, it would be nice to just set the autocomplete to recognize it as valid without having to trigger the events.

Comment: Does the network tab of Chrome Developer Tools show what is getting sent to the database?  I would also throw in some console.log statements like console.log($("#field-id").val()) on page load and inside the change function.  Also console.log(ui) and console.log($(this).val()) before and after you think it's changing.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours of trying, I found a solution to my problem, though it seems very "hacky", it works.  First, here are some of my failed attempts:

```
$("#field-id").data('ui-autocomplete')._trigger('select', 'autocompleteselect', { item: { value: $("#field-id").val() } })

$("#field-id").data("ui-autocomplete").menu.element.children().first().click();
```

I also tried saving the original value and writing it back to the field and various combinations, all with no luck.

The solution that worked for me was to simply destroy the autocomplete and then re-enable it on that field.

```
$("#field-id").autocomplete("destroy");
$("#field-id").autocomplete({
            source: "/lookup",
            autoFocus: true,   //Just press enter to select top item
            minLength: 0,
            delay:50,
            change: function (event, ui) {  //if detects a string that was not suggested (meaning does not exist in DB), clear value and show not valid
                if (!(ui.item)) {
                    $(this).val("");
                    errorShow(this, "invalid selection") //Display error message under input
                }
            }
        });
```

Previously, the autocomplete seemed to trigger the change event just by the user tabbing over the field - the autocomplete would then immediately decide it contained a bad value (no "search" seemed to have run) which cleared the field and added an error.  Now, just tabbing over the field does nothing (as expected and desired), and triggering the autocomplete works fine.

It seems there should be a better solution to this, or it is very possible I am implementing autocomplete incorrectly from the beginning.  I would love to hear additional insight or ideas.

Comment: What browser(s) and OS are you testing on?  What version of jQuery?  Here's a solution that is similar to how I coded a somewhat similar form years ago.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/42933089/3825777 And, here's a discussion that you might learn something from. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406635/clear-input-field-on-invalid-input-entered-in-jquery-autocomplete

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Pro 20H2, firefox (88.0.1), and jquery 3.5.1, jqueryui 1.12.1.  Thank you for the feedback, I will take a look and update here if I find a different solution.